# Find User Creation Date in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to find the time when a user was created? It means to trace the user creation date in mysql.

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: maybe in the binary logs, if mysql's set up to do that, but otherwise no.

Comment: I do not know how to read my sql log. But i think it could be helpful. Is not it @MarcB?

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL users, i.e. accounts conteolling access to your database server, or are you managing your own table of users for some other application, while logging into the database server as a single user?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `timestamp` along with user information when user creation form is submitted otherwise there is no way to track that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new field in your database users table say it "created" with type **DATETIME**

Sample Query is here:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `created` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'user created date' AFTER `name`
```

Here AFTER `name` is the last field of table so that it will add new field created at last of users table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new `TIMESTAMP` field to your table, but remember to set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value, so when the record is created, this field gets the timestamp from when the record is created.

I'd say it's impossible to tell afterwards when a record has been created, maybe with some kind of using binary logs, but i don't know much about that.